# pyside QPushButton toggle background color

Tags: python, pyside

When I have a QPushButton that is pressed with the toggle option. How do I set the background color of the button to be another color other than black? This code attempts to use StyleSheets to do so, but it remains black.

```
    light_label = QtWidgets.QPushButton(light)
    light_label.setCheckable(True)            
    light_label.toggled.connect(partial(self.light_label_event, light))
    light_label.setStyleSheet('QPushButton::checked{background:rgb(255, 0, 0); }')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the pseudo-state checked:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = QtGui.QPushButton("Hello world")
    button.setCheckable(True)
    button.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {background:rgb(65,66,66); color: white;} 
        QPushButton::checked{background:rgb(255, 0, 0); color: white;}
    """)
    button.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: unfortunately, I am having trouble getting the pseudos state, subcontrol :: to work in this context. I would think it would only be : indicating a pseudos state "checked." Not :: indicating a subcontrol of the pseudo state?

Comment: @winteralfs I do not understand what causes your problem, as you should know unfortunately without a [mcve] I will not be able to help you.

Comment: I will try and make one.

Comment: @winteralfs a [mcve] has nothing to do with your project but only with placing a working code where the error is shown as my example does.

Comment: I updated the code as this is unfortunately still causing me issues.